# How to copy files in Android from sdcard to internal storage without corrupting them

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, ioexception, file-handling

My program needs to copy two files (.ogg sound files) located in a folder in sd card to cache dir of the application which is returned via getCacheDir()

i use the following code to copy the files

```
File cache=this.getCacheDir();
cache.mkdirs();
fout=new FileOutputStream(cache.getAbsolutePath()+"/file1.ogg");
fin=new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirector+"/imported/file1.ogg");

byte[] buf = new byte[128];
int len;
while ((len = fin.read(buf,0,128))>-1){
    fout.write(buf, 0, len);
}

fout.close();
fin.close();
```

the code compiles and runs without any error, both files are copied and have the same size as their original files,
 but when my program tries to play those .ogg files IO exception occurs also when i try to play the copied files in my pc they produce error.

however if i copy them from one to another folder on the sd card it plays fine.
that means copying from external to external media is ok but from external to internal is causing corruption!

**EDIT**

Here is what I found from my experiment and observations:

A) copying original file programatically to internal storage -> fails to play file

B) copying original file directly to internal storage (I have root access) -> plays fine

C) copying the programmatically copied files directly back to anywhere in sd card -> plays fine again (AMAZING!)

NOTE:-here copying directly means using copy paste from Android OS

to my sense somehow the copied file doesn't work just after copying it , but once it is moved to sd card it starts working again.

**FTW man!**

Comment: Having the same *size* doesn't mean the *contents* are the same. You say the copied files don't play on your PC. Compare the files, byte by byte with a file compare program.

Comment: they aren't same .. i viewed both using notepad they show different data!

Comment: Notepad isn't a file compare program. If you look at the actual byte by byte differences, you might find a clue as to why this is happening.

Comment: the copied files **neither play on the device nor on the PC** while _original files play just fine_

Comment: can you suggest me one? anyway the character pattern in notepad is different for original and copied. but for any file copied from sd card to sdcard show same patterns thats enough to prove they aren't same in first case

Comment: Total Commander can compare files (ghisler.com)

Comment: A quick google shows http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/ can do this.

Comment: if you are using ubuntu "meld" is also a good file comparison program...

Answer (score 0):

The answer maybe that you are using cache rather than internal memory. No guarantees on cache.

Comment: ya sure ! but cache are meant for the use not to corrupt files